# Combo ports and SFP

Tags: router, hardware, switch, sfp, networking

I have Netgear GSM7324s prosafe switch. Switch has 24x1G ports. 4 ports are labeled as combo ports while 2 are labeled as SFP ports. 
I connected 2 PCs (each having 1gig and 10Gig NICs), with the switch using 1 & 10 Gig cables. Whenever, I ping the PCs the pinging is not working. 
As soon as, I removed the 10G cables, the ping starts working.

Can someone please explain that what's going on. Also it would be very helpful if you can tell me the concept of combo ports, SFP ports in easy words?

Answer (score 1):

That switch doesn't have any 10GigE ports, it's a 1GigE-only switch, hence why it uses the term 'SFP' not 'SFP+'. It's as simple as that.